# Django template - set checkbox checked if object.val == true

Tags: javascript, python, django, checkbox, django-templates

I'm junior backend dev. I don't know how to use JS.

I can't set

```
<input type="checkbox" name="player_check">
```

true... 
or reverse i can't set

```
<input type="checkbox" name="player_check" checked>
```

false.

My code:

```
<table id="some_table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Prepared</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for player in players %}
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="player_check">
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Let's say in 'players' I have 5 players, each player has a value "player_check".

Two of them have:

```
player.player_check = True
```

Rest:

```
player.player_check = False
```

I'm trying to initiate checkbox in my table with these values using {{}} or {% %}

I've tried:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="player_check" value=1>
<input type="checkbox" name="player_check" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="player_check" value="True">
<input type="checkbox" name="player_check" value=True>
<input type="checkbox" name="player_check" value="checked">
```

Nothing works...
Then i found that checkbox has a parametr checked so:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="player_check" checked>
```

That was ok BUT... now i cant turn it off:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="player_check" checked="false">
<input type="checkbox" name="player_check" checked="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="player_check" checked=0>
<input type="checkbox" name="player_check" checked="unchecked">
```

So i decided to use django templpates + change in python code:
Now **player.player_check equals checked or unchecked**

It still doesn't work! Now i can't put {{ }} without name like "something"={{ foo }}

Now i have 0 ideas what i can do more to make it work... Maybe JS? but i cant believe there is no right way to do it just in django/python. ;/

Comment: What's the reason you are not using a Django form, which will take care of this for you?

Comment: It's old project from my company, and it was made like this. I took care of this project, mostly I'm learning and doing staff in backend API, but sometimes there are requirements to make something in frontend and for now it's a bit killing me :P, few more weeks and I hope that kind of easy problems won't appear 
Thanks for answer ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this with for example an `{% if ... %}` tag:

```
{% for player in players %}
<tr>
  <td>
  <input type="checkbox" name="player_check"{% if player.player_check %} checked{% endif %}>
  </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

But I think you better use Django forms, which will handle this in a more elegant way for you: you specify the form field, and Django will handle the rest.

Comment: Thanks! Few minutes before you answered i found out how to do this but your proposal is much better I used if statement with one checkbox thats off and in else I wrote a code for second checkbox thats on. Now I have to change it ;)

Thanks for answer!

Comment: @AdrianKurzeja: well that would work as well :) but makes it less extendible. If you would later add other attributes to the `<input>` tag, it would mean that you need to specify those twice (and perhaps even more times).

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use the `yesno` filter.

```
  <input name="allowed" 
         type="checkbox" {{ player.player_check |yesno:"checked," }}>
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#yesno